# Rider IIS Publish cant select current project

Tags: c#, iis, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have a problem. I want to set up a publish profile in IIS, but the configurator cannot select the project I need. Screenshot below. Help.

I try some helps, but it  not working for me. I visited official site, but it didn't helped me.

[image: screenshot]